# Multi users safe SQL Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlconnection

I have an object below:

```
public class DatabaseAccess
{
    private static string sConnStr;
    private static SqlConnection sqlConn;

    private static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sConnStr))
            {
                sConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            }
            return sConnStr;
        }
    }

    public static int OpenConnection
    {
        get
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static SqlConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (sqlConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                sqlConn.Open();
            }
            return sqlConn;
        }
    }
}
```

So whenever I need a connection in my web application, I use something like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection cnn = DatabaseAccess.Connection)
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("MyAStoredProcedure", cnn))
    {
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
}

return dt;
```

It all seems well except when there are 2 users running the codes at the same time, I will get in my web application the following error:

**There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command needs to be Closed.**

I need some advice how do I resolve the above issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation why your `Connection` must be `static` (which is the reason you see the error)?

Comment: I have a lot of other database operations so that I will just use the same static connection. So it looks like this is the cause of the error, how do I put it nicely then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're sharing connection objects - don't do that. `DatabaseAccess.Connection` should create a *new `SqlConnection`* every time.

Comment: Does it mean I should just put sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString); and sqlConn.Open(); in DatabaseAccess.Connection?

Comment: @StevenYong, yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Also, don't forget to close the connection once you're done. Ekad's approach below is a good one.

Comment: I believe when I use using (SqlConnection cnn = DatabaseAccess.Connection), it's closing it properly right? Thanks everyone!

Comment: @StevenYong, yes with the `using` statement you're disposing the `new`ed up connection properly.

Answer (score 3):

Try to create a new instance of `SqlConnection` in the `using` statement

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    cnn.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("MyAStoredProcedure", cnn))
    {
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
}

return dt;
```